# Instantiating class with internal constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, constructor

I am trying to create a new instance of a class that looks to only have two constructors, both of which are internal.

The code for this class can be found at this link: [link](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/blob/dev/src/Discord.Net.Commands/Builders/CommandBuilder.cs#L29)

Essentially, here's what the code for the constructor looks like:

```
    //Automatic
    internal CommandBuilder(ModuleBuilder module)
    {
        Module = module;

        _preconditions = new List<PreconditionAttribute>();
        _parameters = new List<ParameterBuilder>();
        _attributes = new List<Attribute>();
        _aliases = new List<string>();
    }
    //User-defined
    internal CommandBuilder(ModuleBuilder module, string primaryAlias, Func<ICommandContext, object[], IServiceProvider, CommandInfo, Task> callback)
        : this(module)
    {
        Discord.Preconditions.NotNull(primaryAlias, nameof(primaryAlias));
        Discord.Preconditions.NotNull(callback, nameof(callback));

        Callback = callback;
        PrimaryAlias = primaryAlias;
        _aliases.Add(primaryAlias);
    }
```

I'm lost with trying to create a new CommandBuilder object.

Comment: Hello fellow John! Since the class is `internal`, I'm inclined to think that manually instantiating is not the right way to construct this object. I imagine another object is responsible for constructing it, perhaps the `ModelBuilder`.

Comment: I've never used this library, nor have I seen the docs, but a quick look through the code suggests to me that the starting point is actually the `CreateModuleAsync` method in [`CommandService`](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/blob/b52b54d80c1ea8e6dfd31fa6ea9331597039761f/src/Discord.Net.Commands/CommandService.cs), since this can instantiate `ModuleBuilder` objects, and `ModuleBuilder` objects can instantiate `CommandBuilder` objects.

Comment: You'll probably want to look at the [Commands docs](https://discord.foxbot.me/stable/guides/commands/intro.html).

Comment: @John thanks for the reply. I have been trying to read their docs but it looks like they only show examples for how to create a command statically in a command handler. I am trying to create one at run time using the commandbuilder.

Comment: I see. It does look like the CommandService is where you need to start from, so I'd try that next :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you could do that by using reflection:

Find the first(or whatever) defined contructor

```
var constructor = typeof (InternalConstructorClass)
     .GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).First();
```

Invoke the constructor by passing null if it's Parameterless like this:

```
var instance = constructor.Invoke(null);
```

Otherwise, pass the parameters like this:

```
var instance = constructor.Invoke(new object[]{param1,param2});
```

Comment: note that instance will be of type object so you need to cast it